# "Error building boot parameters" trying to add grub2 partition with grub-customizer

Tags: boot, grub2

Recently when I did an update my Ubuntu 20.04 partition stopped showing up in my boot list.  I was trying to add it back using grub-customizer, but it refuses to let me click ok, despite it having a green checkbox by each parameter:

[image]

How can I add this entry using grub-customizer?

Comment: Try adding the complete name, ie: `vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic`, `initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic`. The linux "images" in your params are symlinks.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thanks for the suggestion.  sadly, it doesn't make any difference

Comment: (I'm unfamiliar with this PPA grub-customizer.) I'd try `sudo grub-update` (in a terminal) and have that script go through your partitions. Next reboot and try.